# Geoserver/Openlayers: Polygon disappears on some zoom levels

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers

I have a Geoserver WMS layer that, when displayed with the Open Layers preview, doesn't draw a specific polygon when the scale is below 1:2M.

[image: Polygon being displayed as intended]

[image: Polygon not being drawn]

The layer is a SQL view with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM osm.adminareas WHERE fclass='admin_level4' AND ST_Intersects(geom,(SELECT geom FROM osm.adminareas WHERE fclass='national' AND int_name = 'Germany'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because your query doesnt include an order by clause. So it is really a matter of luck to show up as sometimes falls behind the large polygon that overlaps it and some other not. Well , this is a guess but I am pretty sure that this is your problem.

so make your query :

`SELECT * FROM osm.adminareas WHERE fclass='admin_level4' AND ST_Intersects(geom,(SELECT geom FROM osm.adminareas WHERE fclass='national' AND int_name = 'Germany')) ORDER BY osm_id ASC`

or

`SELECT * FROM osm.adminareas WHERE fclass='admin_level4' AND ST_Intersects(geom,(SELECT geom FROM osm.adminareas WHERE fclass='national' AND int_name = 'Germany')) ORDER BY osm_id DESC`

**UPDATE**
osm_id is just an idea so we can be sure that this is your problem. Using osm_id for ordering might cause you to hide some other polygons behind larger polygons. It really depends on the nature of your data. Best solution would be to have a field with name "ordering" for example.

Comment: While the problem is correct, the solution is wrong. `ORDER BY osm_id` is obviously a bad idea.

Comment: Why would it be a bad idea?

Comment: Because `osm_id` is a random id. While it will work for a specific case, it will be bad for the next one.

Comment: That is a good point. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: see my answer ;-)

Comment: I cant really do that. (look at my comment)

Comment: You might have the field way_area at hand... or you can compute the polygon areas, drawing the smallest ones on top of the larger ones

Comment: Guess I will have to think of a way to do this somehow as I cant really use other data. But you guys were really helpful in helping me understand the problem ;) Thanks a bunch, all of you.

Comment: Glad to help amigo. Hope to find your way out

Answer (score 0):

When the ordering is not explicitly given, PostgreSQL returns in a *random* order (the order that is fastest to return).

As Ost-Friesland is part of Niedersachsen, Ost-Friesland will sometimes be below and thus hidden from Niedersachsen.

The best solution would be to fix the column `fclass` (`admin_level`) as it is obviously wrong. Ostfriesland should have `admin_level5`.

Then you can use:

```
ORDER by fclass DESC
```

---

From the [data description](https://www.geofabrik.de/data/geofabrik-osm-gis-standard-0.6.pdf):

> admin_level4: Usually a border of the first level below national

Ost-Friesland is not a Bundesland afaik.

---

Instead of fixing this, you could use the official [EU NUTS dataset](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/de/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts).

Comment: Unfortunately this is OSM data, so I cant really restructure it without insane amounts of effort as this is quite a lot of data. And on top of that adminlevels have meaning associated with them. https://www.geofabrik.de/data/geofabrik-osm-gis-standard-0.6.pdf

Comment: I would recommend using official EU NUTS dataset instead of osm --> http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/de/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts

Comment: And yes, adminlevels have a meaning, but Ost-Friesland is still wrong then. (admin_level_4 = Usually a border of the first level below national).

Comment: I know its really weid, but I cant really chose the data I work with as I am using this at work. And I cant really manually adjust 402064 rows of data. The only thing I can probably do is to add a new column and write a script to order the data...